# Given Coordinates of Map

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

```
type Coordinate = (XCoord, YCoord)
type XCoord = Coord
type YCoord = Coord
type Coord = Integer

coordInBound :: Coordinate -> Bool

coordInBound (XCoord, YCoord) =

XCoord

        |x >= 0 && x <= 9 = True
        |otherwise = False
YCoord

        |y >= 0 && y <= 9 = True
        |otherwise = False
```

I'm Trying to write a function that returns True if the coordinates are in a 10 by 10 grid from 0,0 -> 9,9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try breaking the problem into two pieces: Is the x coordinate in bounds? Is the y coordinate in bounds? And combining those together to figure out if they're both in bounds.

```
xInBounds :: XCoord -> Bool
xInBounds x | x >= 0 && x <= 9 = True
            | otherwise = False

yInBounds :: YCoord -> Bool
???
```

What you have right now won't compile because, among other things, the names of variables in patterns `(XCoord, YCoord)` can't start with capital letters. Names that start with capital letters in haskell are reserved for types like `Coordinate` and constructors like `True`. Variables have lower case names like `coordInBound`.

With `xInBounds` and `yInBounds` try to complete `coordInBound` using lower case variable names

```
coordInBound :: Coordinate -> Bool
coordInBound (x, y) = ???
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `XCoord` and `YCoord` are just integers, you can simply check if both are in range of `[0, 9]`:

```
type Coordinate = (XCoord, YCoord)
type XCoord = Coord
type YCoord = Coord
type Coord = Integer

coordInBound :: Coordinate -> Bool
coordInBound (x, y) =
  x >= 0 && x <= 9 && y >= 0 && y <= 9

main = print $ coordInBound (9, 0)
```

But if you wish `XCoord` and `YCoord` were types, then you'd need the following type definition and usage:

```
data XCoord = XCoord Int
data YCoord = YCoord Int
type Coordinate = (XCoord, YCoord)

coordInBound :: Coordinate -> Bool
coordInBound (XCoord x, YCoord y) =
  x >= 0 && x <= 9 && y >= 0 && y <= 9

main = print $ coordInBound (XCoord 9, YCoord 0)
```

Comment: `foo | condition = True | otherwise = False` can be shortened to just `foo = condition`.